# why codeigniter creates a cache file with name controller+function?

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, directory

I build a website on codeigniter framework , I have noticed some folders on root with name controller+function (ex : welcome+index) using PHPStorm. These folders have a cached file for the pages.

The problem is I didn't add any cache statement inside my code, even if I deleted them, they recreated themselves automatically.

Does anyone know why these files are being re-created and how to disable this functionality?

Comment: The problem here was because of phpstorm it cashes the files ,

Answer (score 0):

```
$db['default']['cache_on'] = TRUE;
```

make this false
on your config database.php

Answer (score -1):

Here `_output()` method write cache files (if you have caching enabled) while any controller(`having _output()` method) call.

You can disable cache by this code:

```
    /*cache control*/
    $this->output->set_header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . ' GMT');('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    $this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
    $this->output->set_header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

Just put above code in the __construct function of controller.

Comment: Unfortunately , it didn't worked .
the folders still created

Comment: Please check for `$this->output->cache();` into controller. If it exist then comment it and check.